# Tengo una duda de dockerfile ¿que significa la palabra clave AS?

Tags: imagen, docker, docker-compose

tengo una pequeña duda, es que tengo un dockerfile y me encuentro con que arranca con la sigueinte imagen:

```
FROM node:16-alpine AS development
```

no entiendo que significa la palabra clave AS, veo que hace referencia a development pero no entiendo que significa eso. Agradezco mucho si alguno sabe que significa

Comment: Normalmente en programación el término **AS** se usa para sustituir un nombre por otro. Su traducción más literal supongo que sería **COMO**, y en este caso creo que se pretende sustituir el termino `node:16-alpine` por `development` para usarlo después más cómodamente.  Puedo estar totalmente equivocado, claro, pero a simple vista es lo que me parece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso se usa en construcciones que tienen [múltiples etapas (multi-stage)](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/#use-multi-stage-builds). Así, cada etapa le pones un alias y es más fácil indicar qué usar de cada cosa. No conocemos el contenido de tu dockerfile, pero posiblemente haya otros `FROM` en los que se haga referencia a ese `development`

```
... --from=development
```

Comment: buenisimo, muchas gracias por la aclaración